# Authenticate to an Amazon RDS for MySQL DB instance using RDS IAM authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I am working on RDS IAM authentication, but I read the token is valid only for 15 minutes. Is this  a good approach for connecting my application with RDS  using authentication token instead of  password or is this only for temporary access to RDS .

I have a php application deployed on beanstalk and an external RDS aurora instance with which I want to connect . Consider it production application.

please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, it is good practice to authenticate with a token for two reasons,

- tokens can sometimes be scoped (can do specific things) so if somebody steals the token, they can only do those specific things until the tokens expires (that is why the short expiry)
- if you use your username and password to authenticate and lose them, you lose your username and password. Whereas, if you use the token and lose the token, your username and password are still secure (it is good to avoid using your password everywhere because it reduces attack surface)

When tokens can be scoped, different applications or components of your system can request different tokens to match the exact requirement of that application or component. You want to avoid giving extra permissions to applications and components (and people) when not needed. Always try to give minimum required permissions.

Comment: I agree with your points but having the production application generate token every 15 mins is a good approch ?

Comment: Do you have a specific situation in mind where this is a bad idea? @Goural If you have some kind of stream where you generate a token per message - that will overload your system. The solution then is to batch/aggregate.

Comment: I have a php application running on beanstalk. I want the application to connect to rds. So in this case if I have to use IAM token based authentication , I have to generate a new token every 14th minute , so can this be achieved from php application logic. or is this not a good approach to have new token generated everytime.

Comment: You do not need to generate a token every 14th minute. When your application starts, fetch a token and store it securely with timestamp. When you need to interact with RDS, use token. Use timestamp to determine if token is valid, if it has expired, get a new token. This depends on how much load you have - if it is sparse and in-between then just get a new token every time and don't bother storing it. Also, the new information added in comments make it a different question from what is originally asked, if my answer helps please accept it. Thanks! @Goural